# better treatment for 2 kind of generator results in python

Tags: python, generator

i want to treat 2 kind of generator results. e.g.:

```
import random
def gen():
    for _ in range(10):
        i=random.randint(0,100)
        if i%2:
            yield '_' + str(i)
        else:
            yield str(i)

def test():
    for i in gen():
        if i.startwith('_'):
            process1()
        else:
            process2()
```

besides if/else, is there better way to treate 2 kind of results in test()?  like different kind generator and different receiver idea?

Comment: Do you even need the value of `str(i)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return a `tuple` containing as many bits and pieces as you like

```
import random

def gen():
    for _ in range(10):
        i=random.randint(0,100)
        if i%2:
            yield True, str(i)
        else:
            yield False, str(i)

def test():
    for j, i in gen():
        if j:
            process1()
        else:
            process2()
```

---

```
import random

def gen():
    for _ in range(10):
        i=random.randint(0,100)
        if i%2:
            yield process1, str(i)
        else:
            yield process2, str(i)

def test():
    for fn, i in gen():
        fn()
```

Answer (score 1):

Yield process functions instead of the strings:

```
import random

def gen(): # OR gen(process1, process2)
    for _ in range(10):
        i = random.randint(0,100)
        if i % 2:
            yield process1
        else:
            yield process2

def test():
    for process in gen(): # OR gen(process1, process2)
        process()
```

**NOTE** I removed the strings because the original code does not use the strings. If you use the string, pass/receive a pair of process function and the string as tuple as @gnibbler did.

Comment: Funny, I assumed the `str(i)` were going to be used for something and they were just edited out for a minimum working example :)